# How to make a struct with a generic type that implements a trait with its own generic type

Tags: rust

How can I create a struct, which takes a type parameter T, which implements a trait which itself takes another type parameter S? As below:

```
trait SomeTrait<S>: std::ops::Mul<S,Output = Self> {
    
}

// error[E0107]: missing generics for trait `SomeTrait`
// note: trait defined here, with 1 generic parameter: `T`
struct SomeStruct<T: SomeTrait> {
    thing: T
}

// error[E0392]: parameter `S` is never used
struct SomeStruct2<S, T: SomeTrait<S>> {
    thing: T
}
```

In the second one, the type `S` *is* used, as part of the type `T`!

Associated types don't seem to work because of the trait requirements on `SomeTrait`.

The end goal here is that `SomeTrait` will be a type for shares in a secret-sharing scheme over some finite field (the finite field being type `T`). For a protocol, users will need to track various metadata associated to different secrets to coordinate amongst themselves, such as an ID number for each secret and a commitment for integgrity of their share. So `SomeStruct` is meant to be that wrapper.

Because the secret sharing scheme is affine, I want to be able to multiply elements of the underlying field (type `T`) with secret shares (implementing `SomeTrait`). This is why `SomeTrait` implements `std::ops::Mul` (and also `Add`, `Sub`, etc.).

Comment: are you wanting to state that type `S` is required to be `Mul`, and `T` is a type which is both `Mul` and `SomeTrait`? I think trait bounds would be a bit better than [supertraits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/supertraits.html) to do that, though I've never actually come across supertraits so that I probably don't have the best understanding of those

Comment: The answer from @cdhowie is correct but perhaps not what you should use. This looks like a XY problem. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I added some motivation, which hopefully addresses both comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work you can use [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html#unused-type-parameters) to convince the compiler that you're using `S`:

```
struct SomeStruct<S, T: SomeTrait<S>> {
    thing: T,
    _s: std::marker::PhantomData<*const S>,
}
```

Comment: Is there really nothing else? It seems like the compiler should be able to infer everything it needs about the variance with respect to S by the variance of T to S.

Comment: @SamJaques In current Rust, I'm not aware of another way to express this.